# Delete Statement show successful delete, but does not delete record

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm building a blog maintenance page for a portfolio project in my PHP course. I am trying to delete blog posts from the database. When I try to delete a blog post, it shows that it was successful, but when I check the database or refresh the page( It has a dropdown of all the blog posts) the record is still there.

I've checked that the correct id is being passed into the prepared statement, I've run the query in phpmyadmin, and even tried just concatenating the id at the end of the query, among other things.

```php
                  else if(isset($_POST['btnDelete'])){
                    $link = makeConnection("database_name");
                    $sql = "Delete From blog where id = ?";
                    $stmnt = $link->prepare($sql);
                    $stmnt->bind_param("i",$blogId);
                    if($stmnt->execute()){
                        echo "success";
                    }
```

Comment: Try seeing if the query threw any [errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php).

Comment: @cteski I ran the query in phpmyadmin, and it successfully deleted the the blog post and did not return an error

Comment: @ZacBeatty-Taylor, please could you do a quick `var_dump( $blogId )` for me and tell me the data type? Thanks

Comment: @HarveyFletcher it returns the following: int(0)

Comment: Is "database_name" the name of your database?

Comment: @HarveyFletcher its not the actual name, I just omitted its actual name from the post

Comment: *"it returns the following: int(0)"* that seams to be wierd. SQL databases should not allow id's with `0` or you shouldn't insert a id with `0` assuming `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: @RaymondNijland Its weird that 0 is there, as I echo the blogId to the page, and it displays the correct id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by putting the id in the $GLOBAL passing that into the delete sql statement